# angularjs application - can i include business logic/backend code in my angular controllers written inside javascript file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-view

I am developing a web application with technologies **html,angularjs, java, Spring.** 
My requirement is to create a search page for my application. Please find the demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7yXvtV?p=preview)

I need to enter the details and search the information.Please enter Atlanta in *From* text field and Chicago in *To* text field and click on *SearchLocations* button to view the information.

Few questions which i have:

1) Can i write the business logic in my angularjs controllers which are written in javascript file as the sample code shown below:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('searchController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.places = ['', ''];
    $scope.searchValue = '';

    $scope.submit = function() {
      $scope.showGrid = $scope.Passport;
      if ($scope.places[0].length > 0 && $scope.places[1].length > 0) {
        $scope.searchValue = $scope.places[0] + $scope.places[1];
      }
    };
```

2) Can i write backend logic in my controllers. If yes can you please suggest any links so that i can proceed or gain knowledge from their.
The javascript code which i have written, can i say it as a backend code/business logic. Sorry about this kind of questions but i thought this is the great platform to put my questions to clarify..

If someone ask me to write backend code for this kind of search functionality, how would anyone proceed. Any suggestions would be very very helpful.The code which i wrote is as shown in the demo plunker above.Thanks.

js code:

```
  angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.selection', 'ui.grid.edit', 'ui.grid.cellNav']);
  angular.module('myApp').controller('citiesCtrl', function($scope) {
    // $scope. places = undefined;
    $scope.items = ["Atlanta", "Chicago", "NewYork"];
    $scope.selectAction = function() {
      console.log($scope.places1);

    };
  });

  /*Controller for searchLocations button*/
  angular.module('myApp').controller('searchController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.places = ['', ''];
    $scope.searchValue = '';

    $scope.submit = function() {
      $scope.showGrid = $scope.Passport;
      if ($scope.places[0].length > 0 && $scope.places[1].length > 0) {
        $scope.searchValue = $scope.places[0] + $scope.places[1];
      }
    };

    $scope.users = [{
      'name': 'AtlantaChicago',
      'show': true,
      'details': [{
        "Travel Date": "10/10/2014",
        commute: "Bus"
      }, {
        "Travel Date": "10/11/2014",
        commute: "flight"
      }]
    }, {
      'name': 'NewYorkChicago',
      'show': true,
      'details': [{
        "Travel Date": "3/15/2016",
        commute: "flight"
      }, {
        "Travel Date": "10/12/2016",
        commute: "flight"
      }, ]
    }];
    $scope.gridOptions = {
      enableFiltering: true,
      columnDefs: [{
        name: 'Travel Date',
        width: '5%'
      }, {
        name: 'Departurecommute',
        enableFiltering: false,
        width: '12%'
      }],
      rowHeight: 20,
      enableHorizontalScrollbar: 2

    };
  }]);
```

html code:

```
  <div>
      <label>
        Show one Grid
        <input type="radio" name="Passport" ng-model="Passport" value=1 ng-click="ShowPassport('Y')" />
      </label>
      <label>Show two Grids
        <input type="radio" name="Passport" ng-model="Passport" value=2 ng-click="ShowPassport('N')" />
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group" ng-controller="citiesCtrl">
        <label>From</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="places[0]" placeholder="Type Departure City" typeahead="item for item in items | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" ng-controller="citiesCtrl">
        <label>To</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="places[1]" placeholder="Type Destination City" typeahead="item for item in items | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8">
      </div>
    </div>

    <input type="button" value="SearchLocations" ng-click="submit()">

    <div ng-show="showGrid==='1'||showGrid==='2'">
      <div ng-repeat="user in users | filter: {name: searchValue} : true ">
        <h3>First Grid</h3>
        <div ui-grid="{ data: user.details }" ng-show="user.show" class="myGrid"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="showGrid==='2'">
      <div ng-repeat="user in users | filter: {name: searchValue} : true ">
        <h3>Second Grid</h3>
        <div ui-grid="{ data: user.details }" ng-show="user.show" class="myGrid"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular is MVW framework, the main component is view and model. So Basically its used for segregation of page rendering from Server Code. Now business logic related to client request handling and page rendering could be write in angular controller but the logic which is related to our actual data/database can not be write in angular controller.So you better know what kind of code you have in back-end and decide based on that.